# Jest framework throwing error as "unexpected identifier" for Jquery import

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

When I try to import Jquery like

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

inside test file

or like

```
import $ from 'jquery'; global.$ = global.jQuery = $;
```

inside the Jest setup file, I get error as

```
● Runtime Error- SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at new Function (<anonymous>)
    at createMockFunction (node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:179:10)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

How to fix this issue? Checked the path and node_modules for Jquery both are fine. using Jest version "^14.1.0".

Comment: Could you please JEST part as well.How you accessing it and

Comment: @surenfeb14 did you find a solution to this? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have a newer version of Jest (`v24.7.0`), so I'm not sure this answer works with the Jest version used in the question.

From a note on Jest documentation:

> Note: `babel-jest` is automatically installed when installing Jest and will automatically transform files if a babel configuration exists in your project.

I found the solution on the [Jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started#using-babel) itself:

1. Install these dependencies: `npm install --save-dev babel-jest @babel/core @babel/preset-env`
2. Add a configuration file for Babel similar to this one in your project's root directory:

```
// babel.config.js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        targets: {
          node: 'current',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`@babel/preset-env`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env). Here's an example `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": [["@babel/preset-env"]]
    }
  }
}
```

You can add additional configuration options, of course; the important part is that `@babel/preset-env` is set as a `preset` in your `env.test` object.